# Export fields properly with Features

Tags: 6, features

I want to improve the way I put my Drupal sites in production. For that I began to use 'Features' to export every single content type I created. (I'm doing it on the Drupal 6 websites).

But when I import those features on the production version of the website the only field I get is the title and other parameters. My field's from CCK are not exported.

I have the same module's (and version) on the local, staging and production website. All required modules are installed. During the generation of the 'Features' I added the custom fields I have created.

Has anyone experienced this behavior? Is there any solution? Did I forget something during the process?

Comment: Can you make a sample feature and post it here. I can try to import in. When I can import the feature, then your setup must be wrong. When I can't import the feature properly, the feature file should be incomplete/incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Just because this comes up high on google when searching for the answer (and I just figured this out):

1. Run cron
2. Run update.php

Your fields will then appear. This is a Drupal 6 Features issue only. With Drupal 7 the fields should show instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem. I have a module which I have written called order_form. The feature export contains CCK fields, views, permissions and many other things. I have carefully made sure from the selection the right things are checked.

1. I download my feature put it in the directories then I commit my code
2. I disable the module on staging
3. Update my code from SVN on staging
4. Re-enable the module to see the new version.
5. Mark components that need review.
6. Check to see the content type (module in this case) and see if the features have carried through. This is a CCK form by the way which includes conditional fields. I have permissions not automatically set, ordering is fine however the conditional fields rules are missing.
7. Try revert on all components. Get no new behavior or visibility.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: To be more specific, the controlling fields set up of an individual CCK field does not get pushed through.